# Function signature in TS does allow for additional properties

Tags: typescript

My question is quite simple I think.

Why is the first example (`func`) not breaking in TS? Is there a simple explanation or some documentation you can refer me to?

I'm declaring a type signature `IFunc` which both `func` and `func2` implements basically.
Why am I allowed to extend the return value in `func` with additional properties? The compiler of course verify that `prop1` and `prop2` is present but it doesn't complain that I add another property `prop3` although `ISome` doesn't define such property.

In the second example (`func2`) the compiler complains about this when the return type `ISome` is set.

I notice the difference between a lambda function in first example and a function declaration in the second, that is part of the explanation? Here is the code in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUD2BbFBvAKGWQAcpMSBGALmQGcwpQBzAbiNPJICZaQBXbACNo7AL4ECYAJ4kUqAGL8QCZAF5kACgCU6gHxosudgQgAPEpihhkCTCAbIYyhLUUv1W3WoOFiUCDB%20KBBkPE4KGmQAckpogBoInloAZhTEsgoU2kZ%20FDFxE3NLaycXMGB7MpVuHTcjfA4AoJCwpKjYhKTeZDSMrmzkXPzxIA).

```
interface ISome {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
}

type IFunc = () => ISome;

export const func: IFunc = () => {
  return { prop1: '1', prop2: 33, prop3: true };
};

export function func2(): ISome {
  return { prop1: '1', prop2: 33, prop3: true };
}
```